# Comic with superteam; electric woman, guy who can make things with his mind and a glowing 'wolverine guy' who can fly

Tags: story-identification, comics

There is a comic from the mid-eighties (I think) that was based on a super team in space and was printed in black and white.
The characters I can recall are:

- An electricity firing woman in a gold suit with a fairly generic helmet;
- A guy in purple having a similar helmet shape as the yellow woman, but his power involved creating something out of nothing (it was always a grotesque organic looking version of what he wants).
- A glowing guy with a wolverine shaped head who could fly (probably could do more but I don’t remember at this time).
- A Male and female (Humans) in what I remember, red and blue uniforms.

The only other thing that I recall is the cover had a blue border around it with the image of the whole team at the center.

Unfortunately not Legion, I can't be certain, but I don't think this book was from either of the big two publishers.

If anyone has any clue what the name of this comic was, I would love to know it. This has been bugging me for about 3 weeks now without the title coming to my mind.

Comment: This is a helpful start. Do you remember any more details? Did you see nothing but the cover of one issue? Any idea if more than one issue was published, or who the publisher might have been? Anything regarding the creative team?

Comment: There were a lot of short-lived B&W comics published in the mid-80's, so it may be hard to locate without a bit more info. [*POWER PLAYS*](https://www.amazon.com/Power-Plays-1-Fall-1983/dp/B00DU24C5E) comes to mind, but the cover (while blue) doesn't seem to match the power descriptions, and isn't in space, and this may have had as many powered people as *LEGION*

Comment: I wish I could recall more, I was probably about 8 when I read it (35 now) only thing I can think to add is I believe the glowing guy with the wolverine mask shaped face was named Vulcan.

Comment: @DannyDeLima: Can you recheck my answer to see if it might be Comet Queen?

Comment: Looked it over a few times. But I’m certain the character was male, he floated around in a seated pose like he was meditating through a majority of panels he appeared in.

Comment: Add the possible name for guy with the Wolverine-ish mask/face, and the floating seated aspect for the one character, into the question. Also, you might want to clarify - I assume you mean the one guy had a mask similar to Wolverine's (which, really, could also be similar to Batman's cowl, depending on the size of the "ears"). Also, note (if you remember) if this was a mask or not.

Comment: I just spent some time looking at http://www.jimcripps.com/collections/comicbooks/80sBlackAndWhites.html -- a list of b&w comics from the 1980s. I scrolled down to see if anything rang a bell in my head as a possibility. I've pretty much eliminated "Femforce," "Crusaders" (aka "Southern Knights"), "Ex-Mutants," "New Men," and some others. Quite possibly yours is also on that list, but if so, not one I've ever run across.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have said I eliminated "The New Humans," not "The New Men." The latter was a color comic book from Image in the 1990s.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I found it on the list, it was called the Omega Elite!

Comment: Funny thing -- when I Googled for "Omega Elite" and found a scan of the front cover of the first issue, I immediately thought: "I own a copy of that! Probably bought it at a show 15 or 20 years ago for about 50 cents, read it, and filed it away!" Apparently I'd completely forgotten the title, the character names, the character costumes, and everything else, since the one and only time I actually *read* it.

Answer (score 8):

Found it - [*OMEGA ELITE #1*](https://www.comics.org/issue/304341/) (and only):

[image: Omega Elite #1 cover]

Thank you Lorendiac! It was in the [list](http://www.jimcripps.com/collections/comicbooks/80sBlackAndWhites.html) you linked.

Comment: Excellent! When you answer your own question, you can accept it after 48 hours of having asked it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. You don't get any points for it (unlike accepted someone else's answer, where you get 2, or someone accept your answer to their question, which nets you 15), but it marks the question as having an answer, which is good. Again, congrats!

Comment: For those intrigued by the Jim Starlin cover - he had nothing to do with the interior. I don't immediately recognize any of the creators....

Answer (score 5):

The "Wolverine hair" and space immediately makes me think of Timber Wolf of the Legion of Super-Heroes. They did have a blue cover, as you can see:

[image: Legion of Super-Heroes Cover - August 1984] (click to enlarge)

However, he did not glow and did not fly (other than how they all had Flight Rings).

If this were the Legion, a more likely case is that you got the gender wrong, and it's [Comet Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Queen) who had sweeping hair, gold skin with a glow, and the ability to fly.

[image: Comet Queen]

While Element Lad possess the powers of transmutation and had a purple element to his costume at times, he doesn't tend to wear a helmet and his powers were over chemical elements.

[image: Element Lad - Splash Sheet] (click to enlarge)

And, well, they've had a lot of people on that team. Karate Kid could be one of the two "humans" in red and blue. He is essentially human, albeit using 30th century martial arts that let him fight in superhuman ways. As I think Valorum was trying to nudge me, there's [Lightning Lass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayla_Ranzz) who wields electricity (as does her brother, Lightning Lad) but her outfit tended to be blue (and often very brief) with yellow lightning bolts), no helmet and no suit. I'm blanking on the others, though. Here's an image with a partial roster:

[image: Legion of Super-Heroes]

Comment: Who's the woman on the right with the blonde hair and the lightning bolt?

Comment: @Valorum: Thunder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunder_(CeCe_Beck) )

Comment: Unfortunately not Legion, I cant be certain but I don’t think this book was from either of the big two publishers.

Comment: Who's the guy in the middle with the bunny ears?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: Reep Daggle, aka Chameleon Boy (http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Chameleon_Boy), is forming the ears.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Oh. I see it now. :)

Comment: Note that this team roster is from the version of the team that was around post-Zero Hour (1994) until the end of 2004. This version of the Legion, along with the ones that preceded and immediately followed it, were seen in *FINAL CRISIS: LEGION OF THREE WORLDS*. Point being, maybe half the characters in the currently pictured roster would be recognizable as the Legion from the 1980s.